Using tooltips with [web] exported graphs
I am trying to add tooltips to the graph exported for web directly from Cytoscape as "Simple viewer for current network only", but there seems to be a difference in the way they are implemented compared to manually creating Cytoscape.js renderings (using popper and tippy). Does anyone have an example of how to add tooltips to this kind of graph?
